# Add a button to my default view in iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6, uibutton

I have the following code (just started learning ios):

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300, 600);
button.frame = frame;
```

How do I get it to show up on my view? And to add a title?

Comment: This question appears to be irrelevent because it is too basic without any basic reserch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this 
Write this code in the `ViewDidLoad` method .

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `addSubview` to add to view and use property `title` to set title

```
[button setTitle:@"Click me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300, 600);
button.frame = frame;
```

this code is correct just use `addSubview` in your code

like this

```
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

and try to put tittle using this

```
[button setTitle:@"Btn" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```